# Linq queries - not exists statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have classes:

```
class Person
{
    private int _personID;
    private string _fullName;
    ....
    ....
}

class Employee : Person
{
    private List<Project> _projectList;
    ....
    ....
}

class Project
{
    private string _projectCode;
    private List<Employee> _employeeList;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now I need to get ALL Employees who are working on the same project as Employee with _personID == 0. Employee.ProjectList contains exactly one project.

And I need to get PROJECT on whom are working all employees -> Every Employee has in his _projectList the same _projectCode. This should be done in LINQ.

I can do this in SQL but now I am using Db4o object database and LINQ and I really dont know how to handle that situation. I will be thankful for any hits. (Sorry for my English).

Comment: post the sql query what you wrote?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please post SQL since it is our common language.

Comment: For: Project on whom are working all employees:
I dont have the SQL right now because I am using Db4o. In SQL database I would use 2 times
not exists statement (its many to many relationship) It would be something like

SELECT projectCode FROM Project WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT employee.FullName FROM Employee WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT attribute FROM join table WHERE join for tables [id.first_table = id.in_second_table AND blah blah]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - if `Employee.ProjectList` contains exactly one project, then consider not to use collection for keeping this project.

And query is:

```
var employees = Projects.Where(p => p.EmployeeList.Any(e => e.PersonID == id))
                        .SelectMany(p => p.EmployeeList)
                        .Where(e => e.PersonID != id)
                        .Distinct();
```

UPDATE: There is no equivalent for `Distinct` and `Any` in query syntax, but here is same query as above with mixed syntax:

```
var employees = (from p in Projects
                 where p.EmployeeList.Any(e => e.PersonID == id)
                 from e in p.EmployeeList
                 where e.PersonID != id
                 select e).Distinct();
```

Comment: Note that this will produce at least two SQL queries because of using `First()`.

Comment: One more Q, how can I build this query into this:  var employees = from Project p in db [db = IEmbeddedObjectContainer] where .. and this query

Comment: @H0ney added query syntax

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Now I just has to figure out the second question. I just want to add one fact. For object database (and in my case) .. the starting syntax is "from CLASS VARIABLE in data_source" .. so it is from Project p in db .. etc. but its just detail. Thank you very very much.